# setting up session variable using only javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt, session-variables

I am working on setting up a session variable only using JavaScript.

The requirement goes this way, A user logs into my application using SFTP client with UN/key, if I store the UN in a ctx variable its getting cleared after login process. I need the user name value to transfer any file to the back-end using my application. for this I am planning on using a session variable in JavaScript so that the UN will be saved as long as the session is established. I don't see any example with just JavaScript being used. is this possible ? I am not a JavaScript developer.

My application only supports XLS, XML and JavaScript.

I am thinking something like

this is just sudo code.

```
function username(UNvalue) {
   var sessionun;
   session.setvalue(sessionun) = UNvalue;
   return sessionun;
}
```

Thanks,
Aswin.

Comment: I'm not following -- if the client is logging in via an sftp client, then doesn't that imply that your application is an sftp server?  So you're attempting to write an sftp server in pure Javascript?

Comment: Are you then using some kind of server-side Javascript framework?  (Which? Why?)